# Blazor @page route url define with variable

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a question for Blazor Server Side.

I want to `@page` route url define with variable or property.

I can use now with below default method

```
@page "/route-url"

<h1>Page Test</h1>

@code {
    
}
```

But i want use like as below method

```
@page MenuItem.Role

<h1>Page Test</h1>

@code {
    
}
```

I'm tried above method then throwed exception. Like as below exception.

```
C:\Projects\TestBlazorProject\Pages\TestPage.razor(1,7): error RZ1016: The 'page' directive expects a string surrounded by double quotes. [C:\Projects\TestBlazorProject\TestBlazorProject.csproj]
```

How to define `@page` route url with any different variable or any class property?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### Can this be done?

**Yes**

#### How?

*Page file*

```
@attribute [Route(PageRoute.TaskList)]

<div>PAGE HTML HERE</div>

@code{ ... }
```

PageRoute.cs:

```
public static class PageRoute
{
    public const string TaskList = "/route-url";
}
```

#### Explanation

The page directive gets compiled down to an attribute and has the same restrictions as C# attributes.

You can use the `@attribute` with the `[Route]` attribute and use string concatenation instead of string interpolation to define a constant for the route, ***since that's what the C# compiler supports.***

#### Why would anybody do this?

This is a good coding practice, because you are not hardcoding the page/component name in multiple places, but only in one place.
So one fine day when you manager asks to change page name "Earth" to "Planet3",
you just change it in 1 place, and be 98% sure that your app wont crash because of it.

Comment: The attribute must be a const like : public const string TaskList = "/tasklist";

Comment: It would be nice if you could refer to the constant in the attribute as well as in NavLinks or a tags, but the attributes need to have the / prefix, and the hrefs can't.

Comment: Would it be possible to configure an url parameter in the string as well? e.g. public const string TaskList = "/route-url/view/{Id}" ?

Comment: Yes: I found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587564/blazor-route-attribute-with-page-parameters-and-localization

Answer (score 9):

`@page` isn't C#, it's Razor talk.  Razor files are pre-compiled into c# files during compilation.

As an example, this is the important section of the C# pre-compiled file for Index.razor (Index.razor.g.cs):

```cs
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]
public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{
    #pragma warning disable 1998
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\r\n\r\nWelcome to your new app.\r\n\r\n");
        __builder.OpenComponent<Blazor.Starter.Shared.SurveyPrompt>(1);
        __builder.AddAttribute(2, "Title", "How is Blazor working for you?");
        __builder.CloseComponent();
    }
    #pragma warning restore 1998
}
```

Note that `@page` has become a compile time attribute `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]`.  It's fixed at compiletime, you can't change it at runtime.

Routes are set this way because the router builds a routemap - essentially a dictionary of route url/component class pairs - when the application loads by trawling the application assembly for any component classes with a `Route` attribute.  On a routing event it reads the new url, finds the component class and loads it into the layout.  Any variables - stuff in curly brackets - get passed into the component as `Parameters`.

You haven't made it clear what the line below is supposed to do:

`@page MenuItem.Role`

1. Do you want to capture a variable supplied in the route into `MenuItem.Role`?
2. Do you want to set this page's route to the value in `MenuItem.Role`?

If 1, either the other answers will work for you. If 2, you'll need to consider writing your own router.  A subject beyond a simple answer here.

Comment: I want to set this page's route to the value in MenuItem.Role. I'm currenlty using from above recomendations

Comment: You're into building your own router - have a look at this article - https://chrissainty.com/building-a-custom-router-for-blazor/.  Showing you how to do that is beyond the scope of answers to question here and requires a lot more detailed specification information aka software consulting.

Comment: Custom router is not solution for me becasuse complex solution for me but thanks for share.

Comment: This solution works very well! If you have a *CSHMLT* file then you have to use the following attribute: `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemMetadata("RouteTemplate", "/YourPageUrl")]`

Comment: My usecase is to have only one place for the path, in case it changes.

Comment: @Flimtix `RazorCompiledItemMetadata` works well thanks. Just don't forget to also add `@page`, withtout it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't they allow the use of a const value though?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve that by following.

```
@page "/{Role}"

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using with this method but i want all route paths organize and store in MenuItem class

Comment: @muratoner you can do it via `@attribute`, for example see my answer

Comment: This is not working in Blazor Server App. I tried like "@page "/{MyConstantVariable}" "

Answer (score 3):

Building off of the above you can I was able to get this to work with the code isolation approach.

```
Client/Pages/Foo/
----Index.razor
----Index.cs

namespace Client.Pages.Foo;
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute(Path)]
public partial class Index
{
    public const string Path = "/Foo";
}
```