# Is there a way to set a base path for Razor Class Library's pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor webassembly project which has 2 Razor Class Libraries, both contains views and pages.

What I want to achive is to set `/feature-one` base path for the first Razor Class Library and `/feature-two` for the other one.

Is there a proper way to do this?

In the wwwroot I tried to add index.html and set `<base href="/feature-one" />` also I tried to add a manifest.json and set the `"start_url"` but none of the worked.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894753/blazor-page-route-url-define-with-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894753/blazor-page-route-url-define-with-variable) here @user160357 answered the question.

Comment: What do you mean by base path? @page might indeed be good enough.

Comment: In case of feature-one RCL I want that all my URLs start with `/feature-one` so when I add for example a `@page "/home"` the result should be `/feature-one/home`.